# Chrome export webpage - Not saving changes made to HTML

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to export changes I made to a local HTML file in Chrome's inspect tool.

When complete, I choose Save Page As > **Webpage (HTML Only)**

The final file is opened and does **not** reflect any changes I made to the original file.

Ideas?

Comment: open developer tools, rightclick on the html root element, choose edit as html, select all, ctrl-c and paste in a text file. save it with extension html.

Comment: You are a life saver man, thank you - what a dumb design on Google's part. Saving a pages HTML should very well include any edits made in Inspect.